# How to avoid child form dispose when disposing its parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tow forms Form1 and Form2,this is the code of creating form2 after creating form1

```
F2=new Form2();
F2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
F2.TopLevel = false;
F2.Parent = F1;//setting the parent of form1 to be form1
```

Also, i want to have only one Form2 object in my application but the parent changes so F1 may be disposed and set the F2 parent to other object of Form1 type.
Now when i dispose F1,F2 is disposed how to get avoid disposing F2 when disposing F1?
Is there away to get the onparentdispose event from child then changing its parent then?
[image]

**EDIT:**

i want only green form per each red form but the layout of the blue forms changes and therefore it get disposed

Comment: Perhaps try hooking on the F1 Close event?

Comment: I think this may be a problem of "exit application when startup form closes".

Comment: When F1 is the main Form your app will close. Otherwise, do not set F1 as the Parent.

Comment: the parent form is not the main form

Comment: Ouch. Are you trying to re-create a maximized MDI child form by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get child Forms of F1 in `FormClosing` event and set their parent to another Form:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form frm in this.Controls.OfType<Form>())
    {
        frm.Parent = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().First(f => f.Tag == "Foo");
    }
}
```

Change `.First(f => f.Tag == "Foo")` to your desired way of finding another instance of F1!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global static variable to point to an instance of Form2. For example:

```
public class Globals
{
    public static Form2 form2;
}
```

Somewhere when you create Form2 object, assign it to Globals.Form2 variabe.

```
F2=new Form2();
F2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
F2.TopLevel = false;
F2.Parent = F1;//setting the parent of form1 to be form1
Globals.form2 = F2; // Save it to an global variable
```

Then, in your Form1's FormClosing event handler, set Gloabls.Form2.Parent property to another form object (e.g. your main form) or null. In this way, your Form2 object will stay alive when Form1 is disposed.